# How to import babel-polyfill only one time

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I done a react library that I share between a react web app and a react native app.

It uses return regeneratorRuntime.wrap to replace async. So I have to import babel-polyfill to do it working. 
I add :    import  "babel-polyfill"; on my module index.js file

It works well but I have this Ugly error on my app:

```
 Uncaught Error: only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed
        at Object.<anonymous> (index.es.js:6646)
        at Object.<anonymous> (main.4c81c635.js:11811)
        at t (bootstrap c8114fe78af615bb02e2:19)
        at Object.<anonymous> (main.4c81c635.js:19203)
        at t (bootstrap c8114fe78af615bb02e2:19)
        at Object.<anonymous> (main.4c81c635.js:15866)
        at t (bootstrap c8114fe78af615bb02e2:19)
        at Object.<anonymous> (main.4c81c635.js:18400)
        at t (bootstrap c8114fe78af615bb02e2:19)
        at Object.<anonymous> (main.4c81c635.js:17848)
```

Dow you know how to manage it?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my babel.rc to that and it works now ;)

```
 {
      "presets": [
        "react-app"
      ],
      "plugins": [
        "external-helpers"
      ]
    }
```